# rails ignore adding to array

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ajax

I have this bunch of code here:

```
doc.xpath("//script[@type='text/javascript']/text()").each do |text|
       if text.content =~ /more_options_on_polling/
         price1 = text.to_s.scan(/\"(formatted_total_price)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         description = text.to_s.scan(/\"(ticket_desc)\":\"(.+?)\"/).uniq
         price = price1 + description
         testing = price1.map{|a| { a[0] => a[1] } }
         desc = description.map{|a| { a[0] => a[1] } }
         respond_to do |format|
           format.json  { render :json => {:testing => testing,
                                           :desc => desc }}
         end
       end
```

Now in the desc, It returns this:

```
"desc": [
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Later Owl Ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Later Owl Ticket+Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Later Owl + Chance For VIP Upgrade"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "VIP Ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "VIP Ticket + Collector Ticket &#64 extra &Acirc;&pound;4.95 per ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Skydeck Package"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "5 Person Skydeck Table"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "7 Person Skydeck Table"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "10 Person Skydeck Table"
    }
  ]
```

What im wanting is anything with a + symbol inside to be ignored. so ideally the response would be this:

```
"desc": [
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Later Owl Ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "VIP Ticket"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "Skydeck Package"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "5 Person Skydeck Table"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "7 Person Skydeck Table"
    },
    {
      "ticket_desc": "10 Person Skydeck Table"
    }
  ]
```

I'm currently making this with rails, But i'm renderign it into the view via javascript/Ajax, So if you have any ideas what i can do there let me know :)

Heres the ajax:

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.testing.length; i++) {
    var section = json.testing[i].formatted_total_price;
    var desc = json.desc[i].ticket_desc;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one option is to use select on the `desc` hash. For example, after the line that begins with `desc =` you could add:

```
desc.select! { |a| !a['ticket_desc'].include?("+") }
```

If you want to keep the original desc, use the non-destructive select and put the results in a new variable:

```
desc_wo_plus = desc.select { |a| !a['ticket_desc'].include?("+") }
```

Comment: Hey there! I'm getting `NoMethodError (undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass):` would this be because i've put it inside the each

Comment: Sorry I thought your data was a hash but's actually an array of hashes. I've updated my answer.